# No truth function that is expressed by a formula that uses only implication and equivalence connectives

Tags: logic, proof-writing, propositional-calculus

I proved the following statement by induction:

> Let $A$ be a propositional formula which uses only the connectives $→$ and $↔$. Prove (by induction on the complexity of $A$) that if every propositional variable is true then $A$ is true.

which was fairly straight forward to prove but then there was a follow up question which I was a little unsure of that referred to the previous proof:

> Then deduce that there is a truth function $f$ that is not expressed by any propositional formula that uses only the connectives $→$ and $↔$

By the previous proof it was obvious to see that A would be true if every variable was true but if there was some variable that was not true it may be that A is not true. So by this the truth function may be different from the truth table of some propositional formula that uses only the connectives → and ↔ and then it would not be expressed by this formula?

Does this prove the statement correctly? My understanding of the truth functions and the idea of 'expressing a formula' So I'm unsure if my example is entirely true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can express a truth function as a propositional formula of some sort, it means that both give the same output for **every** input (combination of truth values for atoms). If they differ on **at least one** input, then they are not the same. Since you have done the first part correctly, you should be able to easily figure out a truth function that must be different from **every** propositional formula that uses only implication and equivalence operators.

Hint:

> You already know what every propositional formula of that kind does to the all-true input combination. So make a truth function that does not do the same.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24597/discussion-on-answer-by-user21820-no-truth-function-that-is-expressed-by-a-formu).